Is there Notepad++ equal alternative substitute app in Ubuntu?
I need app that would replace windows Notepad++ in Ubuntu.
Right now i need to replace with sed syntax and in case i make mistake i can undo.
How can i do that now fast in ubuntu? Im now installing virtual machine just for this one thing now.
In notepad++ you have:

SED syntax search replace
new unsaved file current state
All opened file search
Selected folder all file content search
Plugins

Even VScode doesnt have so good 3 and 4 search options

Notepad++ is available from the snap store:
~$ snap info notepad-plus-plus
name:      notepad-plus-plus
summary:   notepad-plus-plus is a free source code editor.
publisher: Taqi Raza (mmtrt)
store-url: https://snapcraft.io/notepad-plus-plus
contact:   https://github.com/mmtrt/notepad-plus-plus/wiki
license:   LGPL-2.1+ OR LGPL-3.0+
description: |
  Based on the powerful editing component Scintilla, notepad-plus-plus is written in C++ and uses
  pure Win32 API and STL which ensures a higher execution speed and smaller program size. By
  optimizing as many routines as possible without losing user friendliness, notepad-plus-plus is
  trying to reduce the world carbon dioxide emissions. When using less CPU power, the PC can
  throttle down and reduce power consumption, resulting in a greener environment.
snap-id: 155ZvKiCILXt4S5Ro8YZmzKHgNPPedVj
channels:
  latest/stable:    8.6.7 2024-05-13 (405) 7MB -
  latest/candidate: ↑                          
  latest/beta:      ↑                          
  latest/edge:      8.6.9 2024-07-14 (407) 9MB -

You can install it with
snap install notepad-plus-plus


How its possible to be 7MB?

@Kangarooo A snap includes all nesseccary libraries since they run isolated from the system. I believe this snap uses some wine libraries to make the application work under linux.
